# Redis cluster is disconnected when single node in cluster is down

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

I have a setup of redis cluster. I have a single node in this cluster.
During a recent redis update, we noticed that the node went down for few seconds.

But suddenly the application which is connecting to the cluster experience timeout. Assuming the connection to the cluster was lost when the node went down in that cluster.

Is this an expected behaviour? Will this issue be solved in future if I add 1 more node to my cluster.

To re-establish the cluster connection I had to restart the application layer.